# Intershop code deploy workflow

Tags: java, intershop

I'm not sure if this is a valid question, but what is the least amount of code change before you need to stop the application server, run `gradlew publish`, `gradlew deployCartridges` and then start up the application server?

It's not clear to me to what extent can I make code changes. 
What would be the preferred development work flow?

Comment: Without a doubt a valid question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure you have intershop configured correctly for code reloading. You should have these settings set:

```
# switch auto reload on for all Intershop artifacts
intershop.extensions.CheckSource=true
intershop.queries.CheckSource=true
intershop.pipelines.CheckSource=true
intershop.pagelets.CheckSource=true
intershop.webforms.CheckSource=true
intershop.template.CheckSource=true
intershop.template.CheckSourceModified=true
intershop.template.CompileOnStartup=false
intershop.template.PrintTemplateName=true
intershop.template.PrintTemplateMarker=true
intershop.template.isfilebundle.CheckSource=true
intershop.localization.CheckContent=true

#let intershop run on all cpu cores
intershop.cpu.id=

#dont let session timeout so quickly
intershop.session.TimeOut=60

# switch all preload functionality off
intershop.pipelines.PreloadFromCartridges=
intershop.pipelines.PreloadFromSites=
intershop.pipelets.PreloadFromCartridges=
intershop.webforms.Preload=false
intershop.queries.Preload=false

# Monitor the urlrewrite.properties files for modifications
# and refresh when needed.
intershop.urlrewrite.CheckSource=true

# The time interval in seconds, after which a lookup should be performed
# if CheckSource is "true". 0 means every time (not recommended).
intershop.urlrewrite.CheckSourceInterval=5
```

These setting are usually in the `development.properties` file under `eserver/server/share/system/config/cluster`.

Also make sure that your environment is set to development. The file `eserver/server/share/system/config/cluster/environment.properties` should  have this configured : `environment=development`. This setting makes intershop load your settings in the `development.properties` file.

Disable the page cache (in SMC), including the SLDSystem (urlrewriting is cached here). I have fallen into this trap more than I like to admit.

With this setup, you can just edit/save and refresh the browser for isml/pipelines/pagelet,query file,webforms,filebundles,urlrewriting and localization labels. Everything that is not java basically. When it comes to java things get a bit complicated.

For a simple pipelet you can run `gradlew publish` and it should reload. However, it won't reload other classes that it depends on that has been modified. Sometimes it doesn't reload at all, I have to admit, I don't know why this happens. For new pipelets and changes in the component framework, u always need to compile/restart intershop.

Like Rainer mentioned Jrebel can reload your plain java classes and I can also highly recommend it. However, you would need a license for this.

Answer (score 1):

With code change you mean Java code? 
In Development mode you can enable the reloading of pipelet code. There is a special classloader from Intershop for this.

You need to restart the server if you modify any other classes unless you use JRebel, or some other classloader which can detect code modifications.

You of ofcourse have to compile the code with "gradlew publish" for all this.
You also need to restart the server if you made changes in the configuration framework.

While developing you don't need "gradlew deployCartridges" for code changes since the server is reading code from your project directory.